# Android adjust top position of a ListView's ScrollBar

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollbar

I've created a controller to add a view into ListView.addHeaderView(...) that will manage a portion of the header to stick to the top of the ListView.  How i'm doing this is by having the control monitor the OnScrollListener for when the portion of the header is at the top of the ListView and then removing the pinnable view from the header and adding it to the top of the ListView's parent view.

This work exactly how I expect exempt for the scroll bar on the right side of the ListView will be behind the view I've pinned to the top of the ListView. I need to get the bar to be offset down the height of the pinned view.

Is there a way to adjust where the top of the ScrollBar starts?

I appreciate any and all help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work OK: It's a copy of ListView.computeVerticalScrollOffset with two modifications:

- Subclass `ListView`, modify your layout to use your subclass
- Copy `ListView.computeVerticalScrollOffset` to your custom `ListView`
- Replace member variable references with getters (see below)
- Modify the offset method to account for the adjustment you want to use (see below)

`YourListView.java`:

```
@Override
protected int computeVerticalScrollOffset() {
    final int firstPosition = getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    if (firstPosition >= 0 && childCount > 0) {
        if (isSmoothScrollbarEnabled()) {
            final View view = getChildAt(0);
            final int top = view.getTop();

            int height = view.getHeight();
            if (height > 0) {

                // The core of the change is here (mHeaderRowHeight)
                return Math.max(firstPosition * 100 - (top * 100) / height +
                        (int) ((float) (getScrollY() + mHeaderRowHeight) / (getHeight() + mHeaderRowHeight) * getCount() * 100), 0);
            }
        } else {
            int index;
            final int count = getCount();
            if (firstPosition == 0) {
                index = 0;
            } else if (firstPosition + childCount == count) {
                index = count;
            } else {
                index = firstPosition + childCount / 2;
            }
            return (int) (firstPosition + childCount * (index / (float) count));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```